# Как проверить содержит ли массив данные

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Имеется поле которое юзер может заполнить путем перетаскивания в него имен:

```
<form name="myForm">
<div class="procLeader">
<label>Leader:</label>  
<ol>
    <li class="placeholder"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
</ol>
</div>
</form>
```

А также функция с помощью которой я сохраняю полученные данные:

```
var LISTOBJ = {
  saveList: function() {
    $(".procLeader").each(function() {
      var listCSV = [];
      $(this).find("li").each(function() {
        listCSV.push($(this).text());
      });
      var values = '' + listCSV.join(', ') + '';
      $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='procLeader[]' value='" + values + "' />");
      $("#output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
      console.debug(listCSV);
    });
  }
}
```

Я хочу проверить поле перед тем как сохранить форму:

```
var procLeader = document.forms["myForm"]["procLeader[]"].value;
if (procLeader == null || procLeader == "" || procLeader == "Drop Here") {
    alert("Please fill Process Leader Field");
    return false;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что я получаю сообщение даже когда поле не пустое.
Пример драг и дроп можно посмотреть [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/97u0peju/158/). Спасибо

Comment: элементы с null и undifined тоже считаются https://jsfiddle.net/e73ds2or/

Comment: в вашем случае должна быть такая проверка https://jsfiddle.net/qpjynnh8/